# Is it possible to pass a function with SignalR?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I imagine it would look like the following.

Server(C#):

```
public class MyHub : Hub {
    ...
    public int DoSomething(Func<int> fn) {
        var res = fn();
        return res;
    }
    ...
}
```

Client(TS/JS):

```
myHub.invoke('DoSomething', () => 2 + 2).then(res => console.log(res));
```

However, with this code `fn` is null on the server.

Comment: You could be it would be open to XSS attacks

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is impossible as your parameters should be serializable. So all you can - serialize parameters in known structure and generate invocation function based on deserialization result.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the function in c# and pass it back to the server as a string, then compile and run it - this might help with compiling:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime